# How can i change developer name for only one app in apple connect?

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

I uploaded an app to Apple Store Connect. How can I change the developer name displayed below the app name? I just want to change it for one application.

Comment: By getting and using a different developer account with a different name!? Why would you want to change the name only for one application??

Comment: When I transfer the application ownership to another account, the developer name changes, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need transfer this one application to different owner. This way the developer's name displayed on the App Store will change to the new owner.

https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/transfer-an-app/overview-of-app-transfer/